# Дискретизация аналоговых значений

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Программа получает данные с датчика, измеряющего напряжение в вольтах.
Приходят целые значения в вольтах. Т.е. если на вход подать 1.9в, на выходе получаем значение 1. А если на вход подать 2в, то получаем уже два.

Датчик имеет собственный шум (+/- 0.1 вольт) который складывается с измеряемым значением.

Это создает проблемы при входном напряжении, которое находится рядом с целыми значениями. К примеру, если входное напряжение равно 2в, то в реальности будут замерены напряжения 1.9..2.1 (добавляются шумы), и показания будут скакать между 1 и 2. (хотя и ожидается постоянное 2).

На рисунке синяя линия - вариант, когда входной сигнал далеко от границ целых значений, и шум (неровность линии), не меняет результат. Красная линия - вариант, когда входной сигнал на границе.

Конечному пользователю необходимо показать **постоянное, не меняющееся значение**.

Что было сделано:

- усреднение значения за несколько замеров, не помогает, т.к. усредненное значение также пляшет то в одну то в другую сторону
- изменение конечного показания только при изменении входного больше чем на единицу, помогает, то теряется точность и добавляется "люфт"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие ещё есть варианты решения, как вообще называются подобные проблемы перевода аналоговых значений в цифровые (чтобы погуглить).

(Цифры упрощены, в реальности немного другие, суть не меняется)

Comment: `усреднение значения за несколько замеров, не помогает, т.к. усредненное значение также пляшет то в одну то в другую сторону` — усреднённое значение потом округляется до целого? Если нет, то, казалось бы, не должно сильно меняться

Comment: @diraria да, округляется до целого

Comment: может не округлять, ну или округлять до одной десятой, ну или округлять до одной второй, например

Comment: И вообще, кажется, я вопрос не понимаю.

Comment: Вы точно не перепутали синюю и красную линию в вопросе?

Comment: @Kromster красная линия показывает, что входное напряжение (в начале) равно 2, складывая с шумом 0.1, датчик показывает попеременно 1 и 2. Для синей линии эти отклонения не пересекают границы целых значений,  и там показания не пляшут.

Comment: @Qwertiy боюсь что не ясно сформулировал вопрос, скажите пожалуйста, что требует уточнений?

Comment: Как вы умудряетесь "складывать" шум с красной линией? Как можно округлять значения от 1.9 до 2.1 чтобы получать "попеременно 1 и 2"?

Comment: Красная линия - это уже сложенный входной сигнал с шумом, поэтому она неровная. Датчик фиксирует целые значения, т.е. при 1.9в на входе выдает 1, при 2в уже два. Получается что при входном напряжении, которое рядом с границей значений, за счет шумов показания на выходе нестабильные. Вопрос как их "стабилизировать".

Comment: Зачем вы складываете сигнал с шумом? Кто у вас занимается округлением, датчик или ваш алгоритм при выводе показания в интерфейсе?

Comment: @Kromster Так понимаю, слово "округление"  сбивает с толку, убрал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь что тут вы ничего не поделаете, если у вас точность округления в единицу, то понятно, что при скачке на границе точности будет скакать и результат... Правда даже несмотря на то что датчик считает в целых числах, то среднее вы можете выдавать в дробных, тогда больших скачков уже не будет.

Comment: Развил идею, добавил гистерезис, получилось приемлемо, спасибо!

Comment: Добавлю, что вместо обычного скользящего среднего гораздо удобнее использовать фильтр Калмана. Он проще в программной реализации и легко настраивается.

Comment: @maestro Большое спасибо! Это то, что было нужно!

Answer (score 2):

В итоге сделал так.

Делается некоторое кол-во замеров, получаем общее значение (дробное). Это позволяет убрать шум до какой-то степени, но пока еще просто округлять результат рано, т.к. на границе целых чисел будет все равно скакать итоговое значение.

Далее, к полученному среднему значению (дробному) добавляется смещение в 0.2, в сторону, зависящую от предыдущего, конечного показания. После чего, сумма округляется и выдается конечному пользователю.

Таким образом, чтобы "переключиться" в следующее, целое значение, нужно чтобы сигнал на входе изменился минимум на 0.2в, что больше чем шумы.

Гуглил по "гистерезис". Так, примерно, работает терморегулятор на утюге (не постоянно щелкает, а переключается только при изменении температуры на значимое кол-во градусов).

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не округлить? Например при диапазоне от нуля до единицы всё, что выше 0.707 округляется до единицы, а всё что меньше до нуля. У вас диапазон больше, и числа будут немного другие, но не суть важно.

Comment: С датчика приходят целые значения, что вы имеете в виду под округлением?

Comment: Ах вот так даже! Я по описанию проблемы подумал, что датчик даёт аналоговый сигнал. Но раз так, тогда придётся считать среднее значение и средне квадратичное значение. В общем чистая метрология.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, если датчик даёт целые значения, то о какой погрешности 0.1 говорится в вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy Справедливости ради, погрешность существует всегда и везде. Просто одни измерительные приборы дают приемлемую точность, а другие нет. Впрочем это уже сильно далеко от темы.

Comment: @Qwertiy 0.1 это шум, т.е. подавая на вход напряжение ровно 5 вольт, в реальности будет измерено от 4.9 до 5.1, т.е. на выходе будут скакать значения 4 и 5.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, датчик сам округлять не умеет что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy это в принципе не важно, ведь при округлении также есть граница, от которой округляется значение вверх или вниз, и если входное напряжение около этой границы, то точно также будут плясать паказания (за счет шумов).

Comment: "будет измерено от 4.9 до 5.1, т.е. на выходе будут скакать значения 4 и 5" - с каких это пор ***округление*** так работает?

Comment: @Kromster Округление к меньшему так и работает вроде. Но это не важно. Если бы округление было бы к ближайшему целому, та же проблема была при входном напряжении в 4.5в. (скакало бы между 4 и 5).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan так а откуда вы узнаете, что там 4,5в, а не 4,4в или 4.25в, например?

Comment: @Kromster смотрите, на входе вольтметра аналоговое напряжение, на выходе цифра,  с ограниченным кол-во разрядов. Когда входное напряжение на границе между переключением из одного значения в другое, последний разряд скачет на единицу (т.к. несмотря на то, что входное напряжение постоянное, присутствуют шумы, которые складываются с ним). Какие конкретно значения - неважно, вопрос как стабилизировать показания для конечного пользователя.